# python-ldap error - {'desc': 'No such object'}

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

So, I am trying to run a search with ldap, and trying to check if I am able to initialize it first. However, I keep getting the error **{'desc': 'No such object'}** I even tried wrong credentials but I don't even get to that error message. If someone could shed light on this, it'd be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, os.path
import subprocess as sp
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.domain.com')
username = "uid=%s,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com"
password = "password"
try:
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
    valid = True
except Exception, error:
    print error
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
  print "Your username or password is incorrect."
  sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Which flavor and version of `ldap` are you using?  What version of Python? Including the _entire_ traceback would probably be helpful.

Comment: I am running Python 2.6.6 and
$OpenLDAP: ldapsearch 2.4.40 

    `-bash-4.1$ ./tester.py`
     `{'desc': 'No such object'}`
    `-bash-4.1$ `

Any insight would help. Thank you!

Comment: Firstly, I would urge you to upgrade to Python 3.6 or at least 2.7.  The [2.6 series](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.9/) is no longer supported or maintained, even for security fixes.  Second, are you able to get the same parameters to work via [`ldapsearch`](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.0-Release&format=html) command line utility? Next, try flattening the `try/except` block and simply executing the statements.  It may provide a more illuminating error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.
A quick and dirty fix to successfully bind is to change the username variable:

```
username = "user@domain.com"
```

the problem with your variable is that the %s is a string formatting syntax (which it borrows from C).
 the proper use of that variable would look something like:

```
username = "uid=%s,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com" %('insert-username-here')
```